# Is Salesforce PHP Api supports TLS by default

Tags: api, php

Does the Salesforce PHP API supports TLS by default?, if yes how can i **check it/prove it**

I googled about this, I get the related information but it's not exact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I ended up doing was checking my wire traffic.  You can do this with tcpdump and viewing the packet capture in wireshark.  Here's [my writeup](http://scotthung.wordpress.com/2014/11/10/how-to-check-the-https-security-protocol-used/).

Answer (score 0):

The Salesforce API's are only available via https urls, thus any API client would have to support TLS.  If you need more proof than that you could use a packet sniffer to verify that the packets were encrypted, but I think that'd be overkill.